# How do I import multiple pdf pages into Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, pdf, import

I have a pdf file containing about 20 images, one image on every page. I would like to import all of them into Inkscape to create a large figure, but as far as I know, it's only possible to import one page at a time. Is there a way or workaround to import all of them in one go? Ideally I'd like to import them as tiles (e.g. 4 x 5 images next to each other).

Comment: A workaround would be to render the individual pages (in inkscape) and so create raster files. Then assemble those raster files for your final product.

Comment: There are programs that extract images from pdfs, e.g. pdfimages.